# Laravel Traits Error

Tags: php, laravel, traits

Fresh install of Laravel, trying to run anything generates a Traits error:

> *Trait 'Illuminate\Support\Traits\MacroableTrait' not found in /var/www/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php*

I have tried manually adding in \Traits\MacroableTrait.php and this now generates a new error:

> *Trait 'Illuminate\Http\ResponseTrait' not found in /home/vagrant/innovedV2API/bootstrap/compiled.php*

Any ideas what's happening here?

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan clear-compiled` and then retrying `php artisan dump-autoload`?

Comment: Yeah i've tried that, any artisan command results in the same error.

Comment: I'd just delete the whole thing and start again - perhaps something went wrong during the installation.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your `composer.json` in a way to put all "*require*" elements together, like this:

```
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "dompdf/dompdf" : "dev-master",
        "stripe/stripe-php" : "dev-master",
        "fzaninotto/faker" : "dev-master"
    }
```

I think my error was that I have written another require block with faker, dom and stripe at the end of the file, and tried to run composer update like that.
Another error may be migrating databases before composer update, or artisan `db:seed`